# When I delete the last tab of the terminal, the terminal window for some reason does not close automatically :(

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I delete the last tab of the terminal, the terminal window for some reason does not close automatically. The panel remains open even though there is nothing there. How to make the panel close when all terminal tabs are deleted? It works on another PC, but for some reason, it doesn't here. You have to close it yourself either with a cross or ctrl + j. How to fix it?

VS Code Version: 1.68.1

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCzyI.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the fact that the outline block from explorer somehow got into the terminal panel and was hidden, if you transfer it back to an explorer, then the terminal panel automatically closes when all tabs are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you enable "Close When Empty function" in window setting.

Commonly Used--> Window-->"Close When Empty function"
[image]

Comment: Turned it on but it didn't make a difference. By the way, now I completely reinstalled it by deleting all the settings and it closes as it should. But as soon as I synchronized with my settings, this problem appeared again. Maybe it's some setting that affects it.

Comment: Or maybe even some extension, because the settings in settings.json do not affect this, as I checked.

Answer (score 0):

So , I was also facing the same issue now here is the solution :
there is a no ports forwarded option somewhere on the screen in my case it was at bottom ,  symbol: a tower with signal run it and the next window which appears opens the terminal section now manually drag and drop the ports option with  the terminal section and boom

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).